# Query through Firebase collections and show nearby users with GeoFlutterFire Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, geofire, geofirestore

I have two collections on Firebase, one called Users, and the other called Companies.

I have two apps that I am trying to integrate together, so the end user app, related to the Users collections, I want it to query through the Companies collection, related to the Company app, and, using GeoFlutterFire, display the nearby Companies to the End User App, in some sort of a List or similar.

**What I have now:**

I am able to store location data to both collections with longitude and latitude, but I do not k now how to display for example, the nearby Companies names.

I have two functions, not sure which one is the closest to be correct, so I will post both.

**First Function**

```
Stream showNearbyCompanies() async* {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();

    GeoFirePoint point =
        geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);

    double distance = 30;

    double lat = 0.023323826086956514;
    double lon = 0.02926080000000002776;

    double lowerLat = point.latitude - (lat * distance);
    double lowerLon = point.longitude - (lon * distance);

    double greaterLat = point.latitude + (lat * distance);
    double greaterLon = point.longitude + (lon * distance);

    GeoPoint lesserGeoPoint = GeoPoint(lowerLat, lowerLon);
    GeoPoint greaterGeoPoint = GeoPoint(greaterLat, greaterLon);

    Query query = _firebaseFirestore
        .collection("Companies")
        .where("location", isGreaterThan: lesserGeoPoint)
        .where("location", isLessThan: greaterGeoPoint);

    yield query;
  }
```

**Second Function**

```
Stream nearbyComp() async* {
    var pos = await location.getLocation();

    GeoFirePoint point =
        geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
    final CollectionReference users =
        _firebaseFirestore.collection("Companies");

    double radius = 10;
    String field = 'location';

    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: users)
        .within(center: point, radius: radius, field: field);

    yield stream;
  }
```

I guess I should try and return a StreamBuilder to check for connection, return loading, otherwise, return the List, or the data retrieved from collection Companies nearby the current End User. Like so:

```
Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: showNearbyCompanies(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text("Loading");
                }
                //return ListView.builder ?
              }
```